# print Linked List elements using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I was solving the [Print in reverse challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list-in-reverse/copy-from/32376898) on Hackerrank

> The `void ReversePrint(Node* head)` method takes one argument - the head of the linked list. You should NOT read
>   any input from stdin/console. The head may be empty so nothing should be printed. Print the elements of the linked list in reverse order to
>   stdout/console (using printf or cout) , one per line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> 1 --> 2 --> NULL
>
> 2 --> 1 --> 4 --> 5 --> NULL
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 2
> 1
> 5
> 4
> 1
> 2
> ```

I solved it using this

```
    #include <vector>
    void ReversePrint(Node *head)
{
  // This is a "method-only" submission. 
  // You only need to complete this method. 

    std::vector<int> nodeList;
    if(head != NULL){

        while(head != NULL){
            nodeList.push_back(head->data);
            head = head->next;            
        }

        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = nodeList.end()-1 ; it != nodeList.begin()-1; --it){
            std::cout << *it <<endl;
       }
    }

}
```

It works perfectly but extending to use recursion provides the wrong answer, why is this happening?

```
std::vector<int> nodeList;
void ReversePrint(Node *head){
    if(head != NULL){
        nodeList.push_back(head->data);
        ReversePrint(head->next);
    }
    else{
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = nodeList.end()-1 ; it != nodeList.begin()-1; --it){
            std::cout << *it <<endl;
       }

    }

}
```

the result is

```
2
1
5
4
1
2
2
1
```

NB: The structure of the Node is given as
     struct Node
      {
         int data;
         struct Node *next;
      }

Comment: In the result of your recursive version, I notice a repetition of the first input set after printing the second. Did you clear contents of the global vector after printing for each input set?

Comment: Ditch the global vector. The call stack is your data structure for the recursive approach.

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: I commented the first implementation while running the second. does it affect the result

Comment: No. Commented code doesn't get compiled.

Comment: Is anyone else bothered that we use using C++ to help with a C-style linked list?  Kinda feels like cheating.

Comment: The global vector is likely to contain [1, 2] before the call to `ReversePrint`.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, I assure you, that if you remove the encapsulation and templates, a "C++" linked list will boil down to this.

Comment: Printing a linked list in reverse involves printing the rest of the list before printing the given node. Note that the "rest of the list" is stored as a `next` pointer.

Scrap everything you've written. You have the function `ReversePrint(Node* head)`. Given `root`, how can you print the rest of the list, and then print `head`? Also take into account whether `head` is `NULL` or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
/* Function to reverse print the linked list */
void ReversePrint(Node* head)
{
    // Base case  
    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    // print the list after head node
    ReversePrint(head->next);

    // After everything else is printed, print head
    std::cout << head->data << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, you want to return reversed linked list:

```
  Node* List::reverseList()
{
    if(head == NULL) return;

    Node *prev = NULL, *current = NULL, *next = NULL;
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the linked list recursively then print the linked list.

```
Node* reverse(Node* node) 
{ 
    if (node == NULL) 
        return NULL; 
    if (node->next == NULL)
    { 
        head = node; 
        return node; 
    } 
    Node* temp= reverse(node->next); 
    temp->next = node; 
    node->next = NULL; 
    return node;
}
```